# Asp.Net MVC validation messages overriding client side validations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

In my Asp.Net Mvc application I have a scenario where I have to

1. Check if control value is not null
2. value entered in control is not "Search"

How can I achieve this with validation attributes?

I tried [Required] attribute on top of modal property and wrote a client side validation for "search". But error message shown by [required] attribute is overriding client side validation. any help?

Answer (score 2):

```
        $.validator.addMethod("ruleName", function (value, element, params) {
            var a = this.optional(element);
            var b = value != params;
            return a || b;
        }, "error");

        $("#x").rules("add", {
            ruleName: "search"
        });
```

1,add a rule,write function to check
2,add the rule to input which you want
check the doc http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 1):

Don't write any custom validation code yourself, the MVC framework can do all this for you.

First, Make sure you include the following on your layout:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

And check that the following is set in your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

Your form should be something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.EditPostViewModel.Title)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => MOdel.EditPostViewModel.Title)
```

And now it should all work automagically for you, no need to write custom validations.